# Access to constant from inside grails filter DSL

Tags: grails, groovy, filter

Here I'm only trying to be DRY on a string key I need, but the only thing
working is putting the string directly into the assignments: `request['RequestStopwatch.start'] = System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Any pointers?

```
class RequestStopwatchFilters {

    def REQ_KEY = 'RequestStopwatch.start'

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {

            before = {

                log.debug(""+System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + request)
                // NULL pointer exception on REQ_KEY here:
                request[REQ_KEY] = System.currentTimeMillis()
            }
            after = { Map model ->
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    // NULL pointer exception on REQ_KEY here:
                    log.debug("Stopped request before view at " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - request[REQ_KEY]) + "ms")
                }
            }
            afterView = { Exception e ->
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    // NULL pointer exception on REQ_KEY here:
                    log.debug("Stopped request at " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - request[REQ_KEY]) + "ms")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it as `static` or better as `public final static`, like:

```
class RequestStopwatchFilters {

    public final static String REQ_KEY = 'RequestStopwatch.start'
}
```

and use it anywhere as:

```
RequestStopwatchFilters.REQ_KEY
```

Comment: I have to try again with the class prefix. No prefix and static final didn't work for me in there. That's what surprised me.

Comment: Thanks for your time Igor. Actually my original post IS WORKING. My bad - at that time I was starting grails in IDEA from an interactive console. Later discovered that that killed reloading. Compiling seemed to work, but the changes didn't make it into the JVM. Cheers anyways!